# Configure CMake to follow symlink

Tags: linux, makefile, cmake, symlink, ldd

In Linux, Consider there is test.so file. It requires other .so (for example alpha.so, beta.so, charlie.so)file during runtime. Its basically a shared library. When I run the following command in the terminal:

```
$ ldd test.so
```

following output was displayed:

```
alpha.1.4.so ==> usr/lib/x86-linux-gnu/alpha.1.4.so
beta.1.4.so ==> usr/lib/x86-linux-gnu/beta.1.4.so
charlie.1.4.so ==> usr/lib/x86-linux-gnu/charlie.1.4.so
```

I want to modify the cmake which is used for building the test.so to point to symlink, like this

```
alpha.so ==> usr/lib/x86-linux-gnu/alpha.1.4.so
beta.so ==> usr/lib/x86-linux-gnu/beta.1.4.so
charlie.so ==> usr/lib/x86-linux-gnu/charlie.1.4.so
```

rather than linking it to the specific version of that library (`alpha.1.4.so`, `beta1.4.so`, `charlie.1.4.so`).

How can I modify my CMake configuration to make the test.so file to follow symlink rather than the specific version? I basically want to make it version independent.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Tysvarev. I want to link test.so to the alpha.so, beta.so, charlie.so file. In the installed directory contains                                            
alpha.so -> alpha.so.1.4 (symlink) 
alpha.so.1.4                                                                                                                                      I want to link test.so to point alpha.so (symlink) rather than alpha.so.1.4 to make it version independent, like this test.so -> alpha.so -> alpha.so.1.4 but now its happening like this test.so -> alpha.so.1.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution by @Tsyvarev will fit for dynamic library whose SO_NAME do not contains version in it.

But in my case the SO_NAME of the `.so` file contains the version number in it. Though it is not recommended to have a version number in SO_NAME some library does it. I have modified the `.so` file using patchelf command in linux.

`patchelf --set-soname dynamic_lib.so dynamic_lib.so.version_number`

This will change the SO_NAME of the library.

Answer (score 0):

For disable *soname* part in the library linking, set [NO_SONAME](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/prop_tgt/NO_SONAME.html) property:

```
set_target_properties(<library-target> PROPERTIES NO_SONAME OFF)
```

You may use this command for each library target, created in your project, or use it once by listing all *targets* to which it should be applied:

```
# Collect all library targets somehow
set(LIBRARY_TARGETS <library-target1> <library-target2> ...)
# And set the property for all of them
set_target_properties(${LIBRARY_TARGETS} PROPERTIES NO_SONAME OFF)
```

---

They said there is [CMAKE_SHARED_LIBRARY_SONAME_C_FLAG](https://cmake.org/Bug/view.php?id=14602#c34667) variable, which affects on all targets. But it seems that this variable works only in toolchain scripts, not after them.